# oozie error with "no such file or directory"

Tags: hadoop, workflow, oozie, hue

I try to learn Oozie and i want to make a very simple workflow.
For that, i use HUE to create a first oozie workflow.

My first workflow is to execute a shell command file "testhbase.sh" containing :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "scan 'hbasedepartementcap' " | hbase shell -n
```

when i tried to put this into the shell icon in Oozie, at the execution i get : no such file or directory ...

how can i know what parameter to set in oozie !!???

```
=================================================================

>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], main() threw exception, Cannot run program **"testhbase.sh"** (in directory "/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1497950602840_0001/container_1497950602840_0001_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "testhbase.sh" (in directory "/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1497950602840_0001/container_1497950602840_0001_01_000002"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.execute(ShellMain.java:102)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.run(ShellMain.java:61)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain.main(ShellMain.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 17 more

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000001-170620022445649-oozie-oozi-W/shell-3f8f--shell/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends

> Blockquote
```

Comment: anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have an oozie action all applications (bash script, jar, hql hive, etc) must be present on a HDFS path, not on Linux File System.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. i solved a part of my problem : i put the shell file under the lib directory and it 's work for shell and hive scripts. i have a new problem now  trying to put a pig script inside a oozie workflow....

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the the path to your script in the "**Files**" list as well. Sounds strange, but if the path is not specified twice, Ooze won't be able to find it.

Hope this helps!